# Performance of factory methods in Objective-C

Tags: objective-c, memory-management, nsautoreleasepool

Is there any difference performance-wise in the following 2 snippets of code?

```
NSString* str = [[NSString alloc] initWithFormat:@"%i", 10];
// Do something with |str|.
[str release];

NSAutorelasePool* pool = [[NSAutreleasePool alloc] init];
NSString* str = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%i", 10];
// Do something with |str|.
[pool drain];
```

I see people trying to suggest using factory methods whenever possible.
Isn't it better to release objects as soon as possible rather than when a pool is drained.
I would see the first type being very efficient in certain cases such as in tight-loops.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I see people trying to suggest using
>   factory methods possible.

I'd guess that's because it's basically the same thing, but you don't have to remember to release the object. Some might say that using the convenience method is a little more readable, too, especially since you don't have to end every method with a sequence of -release messages.

> Isn't it better to release objects as
>   soon as possible rather than when a
>   pool is drained.

You can make that case in some situations, such as inside a loop. That's often not an important consideration, though... many methods don't loop at all and only create a handful of objects.

> I would see the first type being very
>   efficient in certain cases such as in
>   tight-loops.

Sure. So you should know when it is and when it isn't appropriate to autorelease objects, and you should write your code accordingly. But it doesn't follow that you should always try to avoid autoreleasing objects any more than it makes sense to always try to use convenience methods.

BTW, if you're writing loops that iterate many times, you should consider creating an autorelease pool. Chances are, you'll be using other methods inside your loop, and those methods might create autoreleased objects. Using your own pool and draining it periodically prevents those objects from piling up. If you do that, though, it takes a great deal of wind out of the the idea that you shouldn't use autoreleased objects in your loop.

Answer (score 0):

Yes it is. First one is better memory management, worth it if you are doing it, like you said, in a loop to avoid allocating a lot before the next pool drain.